# Google Cache Page Broken - Origin Page Displays and Validates Successfully

Tags: amp-html

My Google AMP page validates successfully on both [AMP Bench](https://ampbench.appspot.com/validate?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.papermoneywanted.com%2F2009-one-dollar-federal-reserve-notes%2Famp) and Google's [AMP testing](https://search.google.com/test/amp) page: https://www.papermoneywanted.com/2009-one-dollar-federal-reserve-notes/amp

I can navigate and view all content on a testing device.

But Google's cached page is broken. It cannot be navigated:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.papermoneywanted.com/2009-one-dollar-federal-reserve-notes/amp

I tested using different mobile devices including a mobile browser emulator.

I have no idea what's going on. Past problems were identified after running pages through the validator. But all my pages validate!

Any ideas? Thanks very much for your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using update-cache request ? 
Adding the Help Article Link for your convenience : https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache

Comment: Provide more information about your proposal, not just the link to it.

Comment: Yes, I implemented that prior to receiving your reply. The problem was actually a Div layer in my WP output. After that was fixed, I created an update-cache script to refresh all pages. I also added a custom function to refresh AMP pages on publish (new) or update (old).